# jquery fading background images

Tags: jquery, image, background, fadein, fadeout

I'm pretty new to jQuery, but I'm looking for a simple script to loop 3 or 4 background images in a header by fading them in and out.  They're transparent pngs, so a lot of the sliders I've tried for this won't work.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

EDIT:  I've got this working, but I can't figure out how to fade in/fade out

```
setInterval(function() {
    var source = $("#background-images img:first").attr("src");
    $('#background-images img:first').appendTo($('#background-images'));
    $('#fading-images-container').css('background', 'url(' + source + ') no-repeat');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the jQuery cycle plugin?  I haven't specifically checked that it works with transparent PNGs, but it's never failed me before.  http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Cycle Plugin - Basic Demo</title>

<style type="text/css">
.slideshow { height: 232px; width: 300px; margin: auto }
.slideshow img { padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #eee; }
</style>
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="slideshow">
    <img src="IMG_2624.JPG" width="500" height="500" />
    <img src="IMG_2625.JPG" width="500" height="500" />
    <img src="IMG_2626.JPG" width="500" height="500" />
    <img src="IMG_2627.JPG" width="500" height="500" />     
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I make reference to this link 
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/basic.html